# How to select [ParentName] from the same table based on [ParentId]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure like so (simplified):

```
Id    ParentId    Name    Desc
------------------------------
1     NULL        A
2     NULL        B
3     1           A1
4     1           A2
5     2           B1
```

It's a big table and can be very painful to look through. So I want to create a view that will display data in slightly better way:

```
Id    ParentId    ParentName    Name    Desc
--------------------------------------------
1     NULL                      A
3     1           A             A1
4     1           A             A2
2     NULL                      B
5     2           B             B1
```

My problem is getting that `ParentName` into SELECT query. I obviously (tried) can't do:

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, (SELECT Name FROM myTable WHERE Id = ParentId) AS ParentName, Name, Desc FROM myTable INNER JOIN .. WHERE ... GROUP BY etc.
```

Do I have to resort to Common Table Expression (CTE) to get this done ?

Comment: It seems like a simple join can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `CTE`, You can consider to do that by simple `self-join` concept:

```
Select T1.Id, T1.ParentId, ParentTable.Name as ParentName, T1.Name, T1.[Desc]
From tableName T1
Left join tableName ParentTable
on T1.ParentId = ParentTable.Id    
order by Name
```

More reference on [Self-Join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx) from Microsoft's TechNet (ref pointer credited to [destination-data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572928/destination-data))

Comment: Here is the docs on [self joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx), from Microsoft's TechNet.

Comment: Yep, that pretty much was the solution. Don't know why I was thinking of CTE.

Comment: @iiminov Maybe because CTE is usually the first thing comes up in our mind? ;) and yes, you could solve it by simple self-join.

Answer (score 1):

Your example has one parent level only. If there might be deeper nestings you could use a recursive CTE. In this example I added two more elements as children below children:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT,ParentId INT, Name VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,NULL,'A')
,(2,NULL,'B')
,(3,1,'A1')
,(4,1,'A2')
,(5,2,'B1')
,(6,4,'A2a')
,(7,6,'A2a1')
;

WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT Id,ParentId,Name,Name AS FullPath 
    FROM @tbl AS tbl 
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.*
          ,derived.FullPath + '/' + a.Name
    FROM RecursiveCTE AS derived 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT Id,ParentId,Name FROM @tbl AS innerTbl WHERE innerTbl.ParentId=derived.Id) AS a
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
```

The result

```
Id  ParentId  Name  FullPath
1   NULL      A     A
2   NULL      B     B
5   2         B1    B/B1
3   1         A1    A/A1
4   1         A2    A/A2
6   4         A2a   A/A2/A2a
7   6         A2a1  A/A2/A2a/A2a1
```

Comment: Sorry buddy got you to do so much work needlessly. Your keen has spotted one level of nesting which is never going to be exceeded. But it's good to know what I can do with recursion. Thanks.

Comment: @iiminov no problem :-) I really love such little riddles. Whenever I get the feeling that I need a break, I turn to SO and solve some "foreign" problems. Clears my brain and is fun! Happy coding!